# How to test deferred Go statements?

Tags: go, testing, defer-keyword

How can I test `doStuff` function? (Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/aPFSlaBLgX)

```
package myPackage

var locked = false

func doStuff() {
    defer unlock()
    lock()
    // some task that can cause errors
    // need to test if lock was really unlocked
    // this is just a simple example, things can go complex on real world
    panic("!")
}

func lock() {
    locked = true
}

func unlock() {
    locked = false
}
```

In other words: how to test code that uses `defer` statements? What general strategies should be used to test deferred calls? If there are no general practice, how to test this specific code?

PS: Go playground only allows `package main`

Comment: For what purpose? Are you trying to assert that the deferred method has executed?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to assert that deferred call had the expected effect. In that example the expected effect is to print "unlocked" to stdout.

Comment: To test a `sync.Mutex` you need to try to unlock it when it should be already unlocked. This should lead to a runtime error that you will need to intercept. "Unlock unlocks m. It is a run-time error if m is not locked on entry to Unlock" http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex.Unlock . There isn't really any general answer, as the test will always be to check that the deferred function has left the program in the expected state.

Comment: Ok, found an answer! \o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

> To test a panicked state the assertions should be deffered

Looks like that to test a `panic` state we should `defer` the test assertions:

```
package myPackage

import "testing"

func TestLock(t *testing.T) {
    defer func (){
        if locked == true {
            t.Error("Expected locked to be false but got locked =", locked)
        }
    }() // do assertions on panicked state ↑
    defer func (){ recover() }() // recover from panic ↑
    doStuff() // this will panic and code execution will flow up ↑
    // and, of course, execution will never reach below this line ---
    // don't put assertions here
}
```

This happens because no code is executed below `doStuff()` since we are simulating a `panic`, therefore the assertions should be deferred so they will be on "panicked scope".

Comment: Reverse that order, defer is a stack, so the second function will be called before the recover.

Comment: Good catch! I think I tried to create a general example but what I'm doing is way more complex and difficult to express in a small code snippet here. In my case the lock depends on many things persisted somewhere else, not a bool var, hence the need to test it :)

Comment: Anyway, the lesson might be: "to test a panicked state you need to defer the tests too".